# Mongoose Error After upgrading node from 0.10.35 to 6.2.0 and mongoose from 3.2.x to 4.6.x

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Recently node.js application was upgrade to new version(6.2.0) and related modules were updated too.

```
node from 0.10.35 to 6.2.0 
Mongoose from 3.0.7 to 4.6.0
```

We faced many problems.

Problem 1:

Getter and setter weren't called for the latest version of mongoose so we went to solve by following the article mentioned here

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2986

Now some how the getter and setter are now called.
which solves my problem. we used the embedded schemas option

Now the second issue has been arrived

Problem 2:  whenever we insert or update we Get the below error

```
Error: Cast to embedded failed for value "{some json} at path
```

Kind of Confused what to do to solve this?

A help would be highly appreciated!!!

Below is the sample of what i m trying to convey

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost');

Schema = mongoose.Schema;




function encrypt(text) {
    return text
} 

function decrypt(text) {
    return text
}

var bischema = new Schema ({
  firstname: { type: String, get: decrypt, set: encrypt},
  middlename: { type: String, get: decrypt, set: encrypt},
  lastname: { type: String, get: decrypt, set: encrypt},
  gender: { type: String, get: decrypt, set: encrypt}
});
bischema.set('toJSON', { getters: true, setters: true});
bischema.set('toObject', { getters: true, setters: true});


var patientSchema = new Schema({basicinformation: [bischema]});


patientSchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true, setters: true});
patientSchema.set('toObject', { getters: true, setters: true});

mongoose.model('Patient', patientSchema);

var Patient = mongoose.model('Patient');


var ram = new Patient({ basicinformation:[{firstname:   'Ramesh',middlename:'',lastname:'Venugopal'}]});

ram.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
 console.log('saved');
   }});


Patient.find(function (err,doc) {
 if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
  }
});
```

Comment: I think the issue specifically has to do with the data you're passing (the `{ some json }`) when the error occurs. The example code you're showing works just fine.

Comment: Yes buddy you are correct but did you anywhere had such weird issue. what could be the root cause? any guess

Comment: What exactly is the data that you're trying to pass to it? It sounds like it contains properties that cannot be cast to string (although I'm not sure if casting happens before or after setters). Is the output of the `encrypt()` function a string, or perhaps a buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we got the issue when we upgrade 
Mongoose from 3.0.7 to 4.6.0

Mongoose 3.0.7  didn't throw any error or warning when you pass a string value to number key defined in the schema

But when we ungraded the mongoose to 4.6.0 the mongoose library started throwing error when you pass a string value to number key defined in the schema

The Root Cause was the previous programmer working on this didn't do strict data type checking and the problem occurred when we upgraded the mongoose version

Comment: According to mongoose docs setters is not anymore and option for 'toJSON' and 'toObject': http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject